# How do I add a task in a react to-do app by pressing ENTER key?

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react.js .
I made a simple to-do app to learn CRUD using react.js:

[image: To-do app]

A task is added when I click the '+' button. But I need to add a task when I click the 'ENTER' Key.
What should I do?

Here's A Part Of My Code :

JSX :

```
function Body() {
    const [toDos,setToDos] = useState([])
  const [toDo,setToDo] = useState('')
  const deleteTodo = idToDelete => setToDos(currentTodos => currentTodos.filter(toDo => toDo.id !== idToDelete))
    return (
        <div className="bodyoftodo"> 
          <div className="input">
        <form onSubmit={toDo} >
        <input value={toDo} onChange={(e)=>setToDo(e.target.value)} type="text" placeholder="️ Add item..." />
        <i onClick={()=>setToDos([...toDos,{id:Date.now() ,text: toDo, status: false}])} className="fas fa-plus"></i>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div className="todos">
        {toDos.map((obj)=>{
          return(
            <div className="todo">
              <div className="left">
                <input onChange={(e)=>{
                  console.log(e.target.checked);
                  console.log(obj);
                  setToDos(toDos.filter(obj2=>{
                    if(obj2.id===obj.id){
                      obj2.status=e.target.checked
                    }
```

Comment: Please add reproducible code

Comment: please add your code

Comment: you need to share at least the `TodoItem` or `TodoList` code. And especially your effort how you think could address the problem.

Comment: @Danial Sure. I will add Some Code

Comment: @RishabVaigankar Sure. I will add Some Code

Comment: @windmaomao Sure. I will add Some Code

Comment: @Danial Yah! But One line of code didn't work for me. So edited that code. Now its please approve my edit so that I can accept your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with set a function on `onKeyPress` event.

```
handleKeyPress = (event) => {
    if(event.key === 'Enter'){
        setToDos([...toDos,{id:Date.now() ,text: toDo, status: false}])
        setToDo("");
    }
}
return(
    <div>
        <input value={toDo} onChange={(e)=>setToDo(e.target.value)} type="text" 
          placeholder="️ Add item..." onKeyPress={handleKeyPress} />
    </div>
);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could wrap the input and button in a form and include the function to add a task in the onsubmit attribute of the form. That way, the function gets called whether you click the button or press enter.

Like so:

```
const AddToDo = () => {
    // ...state
    const [todoText, setTodoText] = useState('');

    
    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault(); //stop default action of form
     
      //....call add todo function

      setTodoText(''); //clear input
    }


    return (
       <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <input type='text' onChange={ ({ target }) => setToDoText(target.value)}>
          <button type='submit'>Add ToDo</button>
       </form>
    )
}
```

In this case, clicking on the button or pressing enter would trigger the `handleSubmit` function.

Comment: I didn't Get It. I am new to react.js. Can you explain once more? Please 

Comment: @JagannathKrishna.P.A, I just edited my response. You can check it out

Comment: @JagannathKrishna.P.A Please don't upvote my answer

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a form you can do the below by adding on the onSubmit

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
  const [todo, setTodo] = useState("");

  const handleAddTodo = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    setTodos([...todos, todo]);

    setTodo("");
  };

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setTodo(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>Todos</h2>
      <form onSubmit={handleAddTodo}>
        <label>
          New Todo
          <input value={todo} onChange={handleChange} />
        </label>
      </form>

      <ul>
        {todos.map((t, i) => (
          <li key={i}>{t}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Else, you can just use the input and hook up a listener on  Key Up / Key Down and if the Key Code is Enter (13).You can trigger to add the Todo

```js
 const handleKeyUp = (e) =>{
    if(e.keyCode === 13){
      handleAddTodo()
    }
  }
```

Full Example In Codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/ancient-sunset-mr55h?file=/src/App.js:239-325

Answer (score 0):

One option could be to make it form by wrapping your input field and button inside the form tag and then give type="submit" to the button
or you could attach event listner with enter key